# index.php file shown when trying to load wesite

Tags: login, actions, errors

I am trying to make a website as a task for my university. I used this tutorial: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-wordpress#1-overview
the first time I did it it was fine , but I messed up the website so I decided to purge and do it all over again. But when I try to load the website when I , once again , followed the instructions from the site above, I am greeted by this message :

```
//<?php
/**
/ * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', true );

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require __DIR__ . '/wp-blog-header.php';
```

it seems to be the index.php file. How do I make the website go up again ?

Comment: Remove the `//` from in front of the `<?php` on the first line. It might not be the only problem but it can't be helping matters.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure php is up and running. Looks like apache is configured to show the website correctly if you are able to see the index.php page.
Are you accessing the site using http://localhost or something like that? If so then open your terminal and enter php -v
If nothing shows you need to reinstall php.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! php is running, I got the message :

PHP 7.0.33-0+deb9u12 (cli) (built: Oct 26 2021 17:51:39) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.33-0+deb9u12, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies.


Yes I am running it through http://(ip of the server)

Comment: `php -v` will tell you if PHP is installed, but it won't tell you if your webserver (`apache`, `nginx`, or something else) is using PHP to interpret PHP files. You'll need to check with your hosting provider about this.